# Run PHP from within TPL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to modify a module TPL file and face some difficulties.

I have a dropdown list and want to run an SQL query when the user selects an item from the list.
So far I have tried to run a PHP file through Ajax in order to run the query but without any success.
I have seen various examples but can't understand how it should be done.
Nevertheless here is what I have done so far.

This is the code I use on the TPL file:

```
<select id="statusSelect" onChange="updateStatus({$order.id_order|escape:'html':'UTF-8'})">
<option value="1"> test1 </option>
<option value="2"> test2 </option>
<option value="3"> test3 </option>
</select>
```

This is the JS function I use to call the PHP file, through Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateStatus(order_id_sent)
    {   
    //TEST
    //alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectedIndex].value + " " + order_id_sent);    
    $.ajax({
    url: 'setStatus.php', 
    type: 'get',
    data: 'ajax=true',
    success: function()
    {
    alert("It worked");
    }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

And here is my setStatus.php file which I want to call:

```
<?php
include_once('../../../../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../../../../../init.php');
public function doStuff()
{
echo "alert('test');"; 
return 1;
}
if ($_GET['ajax'])
{
echo function doStuff();
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting at take a good look at your php file.

Comment: first thing I see is you are calling the js function `updateStatus` but your function name is `statusUpdate`

Comment: Thank you for noticing, it was a mistake of mine while i was writing the code to the post. The actual code does not have that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got a solution for the problem, by using the following script to run the PHP file. 
It seems that I had to import the JQuery from google-apis and use {literal} before and after my script.

Here is the updated javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setStatus(order_id_sent)
    {
        var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("statusSelect").selectedIndex;
        // test
        // alert(document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectedIndex].value + " " + order_id_sent);
        var data = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[selectedIndex].value + "-" + order_id_sent;
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            url: "setStatus.php>",
            success: function(data){
            alert("data sent" + data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
{/literal}
```

And here is my PHP file, which is not complete yet but the point was to run the query and now it works properly.

```
<?php 
include_once('../../../../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../../../../../init.php');
include_once('../../../../../classes/Db.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);
    $words = explode('-', $_POST['data']);
    //add code to update db
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#statusSelect").change(function(){
      statusUpdate($(this).val());
  });
}
```

in your code the name of the function is `statusUpdate` and in the select you call `updateStatus`

i wish this can help you

Comment: Thank you for your help but my onchange function seems to work properly. The problem is that the php file seems to not be executed.

Comment: replace "echo function doStuff();" by "echo doStuff();"  or  " doStuff();" and try ?

Comment: Thank you for your help but I just tried both ways and the result is the same.